# Sequences of functions which are cauchy w.r.t one norm but not another

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

**Question:**
For each pair of the three norms $\|\cdot\|_{1}$, $\|\cdot\|_{2}$, $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ defined on the space $C_{0}(\Bbb{N},\Bbb{R})$ of compactly supported signals $f:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{R}$ find a sequence which is Cauchy for one and not the other.

**My (limited) understanding of what it's asking**
We have:
$$\|f\|_{1} := \sum_{i=1}^\infty |f(i)|$$
$$\|f\|_{2} := \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |f(i)|^2\right)^{\frac 1 2}$$
$$\|f\|_{\infty} := \sup_{t\in{\Bbb{N}}} |f(t)|$$

I understand that a sequence $(u_n)$ is Cauchy w.r.t a particular norm if it satisfies:

$ \forall \epsilon>0, \exists N$ s.t. if $n,m > N$ then $\|u_n - u_m\|<\epsilon$

So for $\|\cdot\|_{1}$, for instance, this would mean $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |u_n(i) - u_m(i)|<\epsilon$

I'm a bit unclear on what $C_0(\Bbb{N}, \Bbb{R})$ is. Is it just the space of functions that are non-zero for only finitely many values in $\Bbb{N}$? Is it different from $\Bbb{R}_0^\Bbb{N}$?

I think the part that's confusing me is that this is a space of functions, and further that it is a sequence of functions with finite support. So, I'm having trouble applying my knowledge of convergence of sequences from calculus to this.
I'd appreciate any help you can provide! I think seeing examples of what sequences of discrete functions look like and when they are Cauchy would really help my understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, a compact support in $\mathbb N$ would just be a finite set (so compactly supported means zero for all but a finite set of values in the domain).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please consider writing your second question as a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

As @hardmath pointed out, compact support on $\mathbb{N}$ just means that each function can only take a nonzero value on a finite number of points in $\mathbb{N}$.

*Hint 1:* For the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm on this class of functions, since the support is compact, $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is precisely the largest value attained by $f$. Even if the other values of $f$ are not summable or square-summable, the infinity norm does not care.

*Hint 2:* What if we consider sequences of functions who have different compact supports? What if we consider sequences of functions whose supports vary with $n$?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have that for $f_{n}(t) = {1, t<n}$, $f$ is cauchy w.r.t. to $||*||_{\infty}$ but not $||*||_{1}$ or $||*||_{2}$. Is this correct?

I'm having trouble coming up with a sequence that is cauchy for one of $||*||_{1}$ or $||*||_{2}$ but not the other that still has compact support. can you provide any hints on this as well? Again, thanks so much!

Comment: @Mobius you're on the right track for the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ case. However, with that precise construction, what will $\|f_{n+1}-f_n\|_{\infty}$ look like? Might need to tweak the construction a little bit. As for the other norms, I'd look for inspiration by considering series which are square-summable, but not absolute-value summable (or vice versa!)

Comment: Oh yeah i see! does $f_{n}(t) = {1/n, t<n}$ fix that issue? would it then be cauchy w.r.t. $||*||_\infty$ but not the other two norms?

For the other two norms, I came up with $f_{n}(t) = {\frac{1}{nt}, t<n}$, I think this is caucy for $||*||_2$ but not $||*||_1$ (when computing $||f_n - f_m||$ i get a quantity in terms of $n,m$ that goes to zero multiplied by a series in terms of $t$ that converges in  $||*||_2$ but not $||*||_1$). Is this correct?